# Xamarin.iOS - Using IPhoneSimulator's Keychain with a free iOS Development certificate

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, keychain, provisioning-profile

I have troubles with saving an account credentials inside an IPhoneSimulator's Keychain. I cannot use *AccountSaver.Create().Save(credentials, "app")* without *Entitlements.plist*. However when I add it to my project, compilation error shows up:

> Could not find any available provisioning profiles for iOS.

I've added iOS Development certifcate to my account on Mac and tried to create a free provisioning profile but failed due to a lack of IPhone device.
Suprisingly, when I tried to build dummy project with added Keychain to Entitlements inside Xcode on my Mac and run it on a simulator no compilation errors occured.

My questions are: **Do I have to make Apple Developer Account to test my Xamarin.iOS app inside IPhoneSimulator or is it possible without it and I'm doing something wrong? If so, what should I do to be able to compile my app?**

I use Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 8 connected to a Mac Agent (Mac Mini).

P.S.: Most posts states, that simulator doesn't need provisioning profile, but according to [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39674/iphonesimulator-build-results-in-no-valid-ios-code-signing-keys-found-in-keychain/p1):

> Starting with Xamarin.iOS 8.10, if the Entitlements.plist file is set at all for the iPhoneSimulator build configuration, then codesigning **is required** and thus an iOS code signing certificate is required to be installed in your keychain. ~ [Xamarin Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39674/iphonesimulator-build-results-in-no-valid-ios-code-signing-keys-found-in-keychain/p1)

Comment: Simulator doesn't need a provisioning profile. You can test this with a blank project. Add the Entitlements.plist in this project.

Comment: Running apps in the simulator doesn't need a provisioning profile **unless** you need to add specific Entitlements for things like keychain access.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT I've tried to do this in Xcode on the Mac Mini and it compiled succesfully. I'll try to do this in Visual Studio as soon as I'll get back to work.

Comment: @wottle, so probably the only solution is to enroll to Apple Developer program and download provisioning profiles from the internet?

Comment: If you need to do stuff with the keychain, yes, I believe you will.

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT I tested it with a blank project and same results occured, so wottle is most probably right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time has passed since I asked this question, but I think it deserves an answer not only in the comments.
As @wottle wrote it is required to be enrolled i Apple Developer Program in order to have access to Keychain.
I sugest also to use Xamarin.Essentials' SecureStore instead of AccountSaver.

Answer (score 0):

We have a bunch of Apple Store applications that had their Apple Distribution profiles expired. The issue was gone once we regenerated the Apple Distribution Certificate and created a new Distribution Profile for the impacted Applications.

Comment: Maybe eleberate?